# Hive on Spark execution engine failed

Tags: hive

I am trying  Hive on Spark execution engine.I am using Hadoop2.6.0 ,hive 1.2.1,spark 1.6.0.Hive is successfully running in mapreduce engine.Now I am trying Hive on Spark engine.Individually all are working properly.In Hive I set property as

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.master=spark://INBBRDSSVM294:7077;
set spark.executor.memory=2g;             
set spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

Added spark -asembly jar in hive lib.

and I am trying this command,

```
select count(*) from sample;
```

I am getting like this,

```
Starting Spark Job = b1410161-a414-41a9-a45a-cb7109028fff
Status: SENT
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(RPC channel is closed.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

Am I missing any other settings required,please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be because you use incompatible versions. If you see the version compatibility on [Hive on Spark: Getting Started](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started), you'll see that these two specific versions don't ensure the correct work.

I advise you to change the version and use the compatibility version that they advise. I had same problem and I solved when change the versions for compatibility versions.